# DataTables using JavaScript data source

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to implement a simple dataTables example using JavaScript object as a data source following the template [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/data) (second example). Please see code below:

```
$("#dynamicScenarioTblContainer div:last table").DataTable({ //initialize table with extras
    "data"   : [{"NoData": "no data"}],
    "columns": [{ "data" : "NoData" }]
});
```

Although the code seems to follow the same logic as the example I am getting

> 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'

Update:

```
var DSDefaultSettings = '<table class="display compact" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr><thead></thead></tr><tbody></tbody>/table>';
$("#dynamicScenarioTblContainer").append("<div></div>")
$("#dynamicScenarioTblContainer div:last").html(DSDefaultSettings);

$("#dynamicScenarioTblContainer div:last table").DataTable({ //initialize table with extras
    "data": [{"NoData": "no data"}],
    "columns":  [{ "data": "NoData" }]
});
```

Comment: I am not using ajax source but javascript source. the question is different. If you can't help then don't try to make it worse. the question shouldn't be closed

Comment: Remove the additional parameters. Reduce the complexity of the code. Once it is working add one piece back one at a time until the error presents itself again. Then we can see what part of the code is failing and may be able to help you.

Comment: see the updated question. It's obvious where the issue is, namely the javascript dataSource but it's still not working..

Comment: @george: the close vote has already been retracted. Everybody makes a mistake and nobody is making it worse. We all are only trying to help.

Comment: can you also show us a sample of your javascript object?

Comment: Tried your sample. Works without any problems. I used jQuery 1.8.3 and DataTables 1.10.5. Perhaps it's another piece of code causing the problem? What does your console say about the line of the error?

Comment: @JanJoukeTjalsma I've pasted my whole code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `tbody` element in your table and the `thead` should not be encapsulated by a `tr`.

Reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp

The correct HTML for the table should be:

```
var DSDefaultSettings = '<table class="display compact" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>';
```

Comment: I've updated that as well but still getting the same error. you can copy the whole code and run it and you will see

Comment: @george See updated answer. The tr was also wrong so I've added the complete DSDefaultSettings for reference.

Comment: @JanJoukeTjalsma The HTML in your answer doesn't look correct to me. The `<thead>` tag contains `<tr>` tags, not the other way around; I suspect you know that (based on your previous comment), but just making sure.

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyGrist I accidentally used the original code. It is now fixed.

Comment: yes, it seems like it works with <thead> </thead> (even without tbody) but not <tr><thead></thead></tr>. That was the problem. Thanks